# PHP/Curl monitoring using Fiddler

Tags: php, curl, proxy, fiddler

I've been doing some http requests recently using php and curl and wanted to analyze the requests and responses with fiddler. The machine running the php scripts is on a linux vps and fiddler is running on a windows machine with an open port. This should work but everytime I use the CURLOPT_PROXY option in curl_setopt, it uses an HTTP Tunnel to connect to fiddler and the requests and responses do not appear. Is there an option I can use to fix this?

I've also tried:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, FALSE);
to no avail

Answer (score 8):

I think you have to explicitly specify the ip-address:host of fiddler after curl_init() as follows:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, '127.0.0.1:8888');
```

more details [here](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/hookup.asp)